# Subtract String from String

Tags: java, string

I have a string `1.2 sec` or say `0.4 sec` What I am trying to do is simple, just remove `sec` from the end of the string. I want to do it in just one line. I know the other ways, convert to char array search for space and delete and all after that but I was wondering if this could be done like `"1.2 sec" - " sec"` or like `time - " sec"` or something like that but just in a line or two. If there isn't then I know how to do it. But if there is how?

**Update:**

If I execute this code:

```
String time = stopwatch1.getjLabel4text();
String replace = time.replace(" sec","");
System.out.println(replace+"");
System.out.println(time+"");
```

I get output:

```
2.0 Sec
2.0 Sec
```

Comment: `String result = string.replaceAll(" sec", "");` could do the job...

Comment: Ya, the only way I know how is to use string manipulation methods, as people are showing. The `-` operator hasn't been implemented like that I don't believe.

Comment: `replace` isn't case insensitive - if i see correctly, you need to change `time.replace(" sec","")` to `time.replace(" Sec","")`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Say the string is stored in `s`, you could use `s.replaceAll(" Sec","")` to remove it.

Comment: The problem is that you have an uppercase `'S'`. Try changing the method to `s.replaceAll(" Sec","")`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
    String str = "1.2 sec";
    String requiredString = str.substring(0,str.indexOf('s')).trim();
```

Comment: I think that this is probably the best/most elegant solution. Upvoted.

Comment: The indexOf('s') and trim() just make it unnecessarily verbose. Just indexOf(" sec"); surely?

Comment: user might input `1.2 <3spaces> sec`. user mistake but our code must handle thought.

Comment: then it's better to write `str.substring(0,str.indexOf(" "))` - you don't have to call `trim()`

Comment: `<space> 1.2 <space> sec` now what?

Comment: User might use "Foosball 1.2 Secs" then you're wrong also. Present the answer to the question, not some hypothetical.

Comment: Hypothetical? It is called covering edge cases. Typing  "Foosball 1.2 Secs" is an error which should be checked prior to processing. Having unwanted spaces is a simple mistake and that can be easily handled(meaning no need to show user input is wrong). I do not agree with your comment that is makes **unnecessarily** verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Use substring:

```
str.substring(0, str.length() - " sec".length());
```

or

```
str.substring(0, str.indexOf(" "));
```

- [Tutorial](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm)
- [JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

Comment: So will this change the contents of str only? or a new string named substring is made?

Comment: String in Java are immutable - method substring produces new String. You cannot change the value of original String object.

Comment: I meant as a result of invoking method `substring` (or any method of String class as a matter of fact) on an instance of String class, you will produce a new instance with new value.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove everything that is not what you want:

```
s.replaceAll("[^0-9\\.]*", "")
```

Comment: Well this does work. Can you please tell me why doesn't this `String replace = time.replace(" sec","");
` work?

Comment: Your example uses `"Sec"`, not `"sec"`. `String.replace()` is a case-sensitive method.

Answer (score 0):

```
StringTokenizer tk = new StringTokenizer(str, " sec");
String result = tk.nextToken();
```

or

```
str.replaceAll(" sec", "");
```

or

use `substring` as @Blekit suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Added this answer to say that `String.replace` should be used instead of `String.replaceAll`, because replaceAll uses regex/Pattern class, which are not required in this case.

`String result = str.replace(" Sec","");`

Comment: Will this even make a new string?

Answer (score 0):

What about using a StringTokenizer

```
new StringTokenizer("0.2 Sec").nextToken();
```

It will return "0.2"